# How to open a file as read-only with java?

Tags: java

I have a openFile method that gets a File that's stored in the object and opens it with the default program for that file extension.

For example, if the file `Book.xls` is stored, `openFile` will launch excel in a windows desktop.

```
private void openFile() throws IOException {

        Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
        dt.open(shl.getCurrentTab().getFileDemo());
}
```

What I want to know is the following: *how can I make the file that's stored **read-only**?* I don't want the original local file to be read-only as well, just when it's opened through through this method.

Comment: Make a temporary copy of the original file and change its attributes to read only?

Comment: What does it mean "read-only" in that case? MS Excel has an option of opening files in a read-only mode. But let's say it's a plain TXT file. You can use any editor to open it, most of them don;t have a "read-only" mode. So your best bet for a generic approach is what @assylias said - make a temporary copy with a readonly attribute

Comment: `file.setWritable(false);`

Comment: http://beginnersbook.com/2014/05/how-to-make-a-file-read-only-in-java/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the method [`File#setWritable(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setWritable(boolean)) you could use:

```
// get a file
File file = shl.getCurrentTab().getFileDemo();

// disallow write operations
file.setWritable(false);
```